# Intellij Idea сворачивает директорию если в ней самой содержится только одна директория

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij Idea автоматически сворачивает директорию если в ней самой содержится только одна директория. А как назад развернуть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чуть выше в этом навигаторе(Project) у тебя будет рисунок шестиренки. Нажми на его и выбери там Flatten Packages.